# como se podria incorporar una tarea programada para notificacion directa al correo con python?

Tags: python, push-notification, alert

Tengo este codigo en el cual se implementa la funcion de enviar correos desde python, se necesita por medio de este codigo ya implementado en el proyecto , crear una tarea programada que envie una notificacion directa al correo electronico desde python en un orden especifico con formato de fecha y hora cada 24 horas.

```
@app.post("/remember_password")
async def send_email(
    email: EmailSchema
    ):

    message = MessageSchema(
        subject="Recuperar Contraseña",
        recipients=email.dict().get("email"),
        body=html,
        )

    fm = FastMail(conf)
    await fm.send_message(message)
    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "email has been sent"})
```

Comment: En un ambiente Linux se puede crear un cron job. En windows se conoce como scheduled task.

Comment: tienes algun ejemplo de codigo?

Comment: Un ejemplo es un archivo python que se ejecuta cada 24 horas a las 6AM: `0 6 * * * /mydir/myscript.py`. Para abrir el archivo de cron jobs se usa el comando `crontab -e`. Es una sugerencia, no sé que tipo de servidor manejas.

Comment: no le estoy entendiendo lo que dice, servidor linux esta montado el proyecto